# 2 SQL Clusters & 2 instances

Tags: sql-server, clustering

Can anyone tell me why i wouldn't want to the architect Option 1 for SQL Server clustering?  Option 1 is having 2 different clusters, and 2 different named instances on 2 VMs.  One's Active is the other's Passive.  There has even been discussion to add a 3rd and have an fail-over "order of operations".

Option 1:

1. 2 VMs
2. 2 different SQL Server clusters on 2 different WSFC
3. 2 instances.
4. Instance 1 is active on Vm1, while instance 2's active is on VM2.
5. Instance 1's passive is on VM2, while instance 2's active is on VM2.

versus separating them out and having

Option 2:

1. 4 VMs
2. 2 separate clusters
3. one instance per VM
4. Instance 1, a single WSFC on Vm1 & Vm2
5. Instance 2, a single WSFC on Vm3 & Vm4

Besides the extra memory, CPU resources what other reasons would you chose one architecture over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Option 2 is easier to manage and a problem with one cluster won't take the second cluster down.  Whereas with Option 1, it's all too likely that a problem on one will affect the other.

Comment: Hands down I'd rather admin option 2, so much more flexible in terms of what can be done with it.

Comment: Well, with option 1, can 1 VM handle the workload of *both* instances in the event of a failover? How long can you sustain that?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - That's a great point.  It was proposed to have 2 separate WSFCs so in theory only one could be offline for maintenance while the other is online.  But from problems i've seen with WSFC - the solution from our sysadmins has always lead to a reboot of the servers within the clusters.  In this case it would affect them all.

Comment: Sean, i couldn't agree more.  Aaron, the admins of the app say "we can sustain that possibility".  Of course that's what they say prior to the system being taxed during high traffic times.   Thanks everyone for your input.